# ACTION_SEND - Share File with Different Filename Than That on Disc

Tags: android, android-intent, share

**Short Version of Question..**

Is it possible to launch a ACTION_SEND intent in order to share a file on disc but to have a different filename used by the share than the filename on disc?

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile("somepath/3c72ae1adacb.dat"));
// BEGIN Hopefully something like this exists....
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_FILENAME, "CuteKittens.png"));
// END
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

**Long Version...**

For security reasons some of the files used within my Android app have obscured filenames on disc such as "3c72ae1adacb.dat".

I would like for logged in users to be able to share these files but with their un-obscured filename such as "CuteKittens.png".

Is this achievable?  (Ideally without copying the file on disc, sharing the copy and finally deleting it which seems like a lot of work for something so straight forward).

Comment: Did you find solution? I have similar requirements

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using `file://` `Uri` values in general, as there is no guarantee that other apps can read those files.

You are welcome to implement a `ContentProvider` that serves up these files, where your `Uri` values have the "un-obscured filename". So, rather than:

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile("somepath/3c72ae1adacb.dat"));
```

you would have:

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://your.authority.goes.here/files/CuteKittens.png"));
```

and the `ContentProvider` would know, by one means or another, that the content for `CuteKittens.png` is found in `somepath/3c72ae1adacb.dat`.

The built-in `FileProvider` is almost what you need, except that I assume that the filenames (both original and renamed) are not known at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer and also highlighting the issue with sharing files directly.  So do you think sub-classing FileProvider is the way to go?

Comment: @HaggleLad: I am not sure whether you will be able to subclass it and achieve your aims, though if that works you're certainly welcome to do so. I wound up forking it to create [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), as too much of what I needed to override were `private` methods and the like.

Comment: That's exactly what the documentation recommends  http://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/app-compatibility.html#sharing_files